# How to loop through a map and display only one row if there is matching values

Tags: groovy

I have a map with differnt keys and multiple values.If there is any matching job among different keys,I have to display only one row and grouping code values.

```
def data = ['Test1':[[name:'John',dob:'02/20/1970',job:'Testing',code:51],[name:'X',dob:'03/21/1974',job:'QA',code:52]],
            'Test2':[name:'Michael',dob:'04/01/1973',job:'Testing',code:52]]

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : data.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> values = entry.getValue();
    values.eachWithIndex{itr,index->
        println("key is:"+key);
        println("itr values are:"+itr);
    }
}
```

Expected Result : `[job:Testing,code:[51,52]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First flatten all the relevant maps, so whe just have a flat list of all of them, then basically the same as the others suggested: group by the job and just keep the codes (via the spread operator)

```
def data = ['Test1':[[name:'John',dob:'02/20/1970',job:'Testing',code:51],[name:'X',dob:'03/21/1974',job:'QA',code:52]], 'Test2':[name:'Michael',dob:'04/01/1973',job:'Testing',code:52]]

assert data.values().flatten().groupBy{it.job}.collectEntries{ [it.key, it.value*.code] } == [Testing: [51, 52], QA: [52]]
```

Note: the question will be changed according to the comments from the other answers.

Above code will give you the jobs and and their codes.

As of now, it's not clear, what the new expected output should be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the groovy's collection methods.

First you need to extract the lists, since you dont need the key of the top level element

```
def jobs = data.values()
```

Then you can use the groupBy method to group by the key "job"

```
def groupedJobs = jobs.groupBy { it.job }
```

The above code will produce the following result with your example

```
[Testing:[[name:John, dob:02/20/1970, job:Testing, code:51], [name:Michael, dob:04/01/1973, job:Testing, code:52]]]
```

Now you can get only the codes as values and do appropriate changes to make key  as job by the following collect function

```
def result = groupedJobs.collect {key, value ->
   [job: key, code: value.code] 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.If my dataset is having different array of values for a key it is not working.                                                                                         def data = ['Test1':[[name:'John',dob:'02/20/1970',job:'Testing',code:51],[name:'X',dob:'03/21/1974',job:'QA',code:52]]
                  'Test2':[name:'Michael',dob:'04/01/1973',job:'Testing',code:52]]

Comment: @Studentlearner If your problem is not the one you are asking, how are we supposed to provide a solution?  Please update the question with your _real_ problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (which uses your sample data set):

```
def data = ['Test1':[name:'John',    dob:'02/20/1970', job:'Testing', code:51],
            'Test2':[name:'Michael', dob:'04/01/1973', job:'Testing', code:52]]

def matchFor  = 'Testing'

def result = [job: matchFor, code: data.findResults { _, m -> 
  m.job == matchFor ? m.code : null
}]

println result
```

results in:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy
[job:Testing, code:[51, 52]]

~>
```

when run. It uses the groovy [Map.findResults](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findResults(groovy.lang.Closure)) method to collect the codes from the matching jobs.

Comment: If there are multiple values within a map how to searchFor matching job:def data = ['Test1':[[name:'John',dob:'02/20/1970',job:'Testing',code:51],[name:'X',dob:'03/21/1974',job:'QA',code:52]], 'Test2':[name:'Michael',dob:'04/01/1973',job:'Testing',code:52]]